# Embedded Youtube videos on html page pop-up over the page content in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

We embed Youtube videos on our site (using their iframe code), and when using the Google Chrome browser (ironically) Chrome makes the video pop-up over the page content, in addition to being embedded, and makes every page unuseable.

Example:

http://i31.photobucket.com/albums/c370/joyryde/ScreenShot2012-03-08at103457AM.png

We searched for other people with the same issue, many have reported it, such as this site:

http://www.pagelines.com/forum/discussion/11854/youtube-video-embedded-in-features-with-iframe-causes-overlaypop-up-on-home-page-in-chrome/p1

As you can see, their issue is identical.

We have no idea why Chrome does this, but it's ruining our site.

Answer (score 0):

You might using HTML5 embed using iframes
google chrome sometimes causes problem in HTML5 player of youtube. try to embed it using `<object></object>`

Answer (score -1):

This is a widespread Google Chrome issue that Google needs to resolve immediately.

http://www.pagelines.com/forum/discussion/11854/youtube-video-embedded-in-features-with-iframe-causes-overlaypop-up-on-home-page-in-chrome/p1

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Sq_4pXdZ5p8

Comment: Reposting the same link as in the questions and a general product forum link is not an answer.